# Is a question on the engineering of a respirator mask on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic

Since the changes in the teacher's lounge I'm unable to ping any mods that haven't been active there. So that's why I am spamming your meta :) Here we go:

There is this [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/89917/how-exactly-do-respirators-seal-out-pathogens) that has been rejected over at Bio (too engineering-like for us Biologists) and over at Medical Sciences because of kind of obscure reasons imho (see [meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/how-exactly-do-respirators-seal-out-pathogens)). Anyway, I asked around on the teacher's lounge and they referred me to your site.

Is the linked question on topic here? I kind of like the question and it appears to be well researched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it could work here. Send it over.

Comment: Done, thanks a lot.